# Java Custom Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception

I am looking for suggestion on how to handle exception in java in a scenario, where

```
Class A.test() 
{
    ClassB.test1()
}


test1()
{
   Map listOfExceptions = new HashMap();
   for()
   {
      try{
      }
      catch(custException e){
       // I want the for loop to continue even if there is an exception
       //So I am not throughing now rather adding the exception message to map with 
       //the field name for which for loop is running as key and message as value
      {
   }

// at some point if map has >0 records I want to throw an exception to classA.
}
```

So the question here is how can I add the Map data to the exception thrown ? basically I need the list of exceptions to be sent to the calling method, as part of exception handling. 
Is there a way we can do this ? 
It might be a very silly question if the answer is wellknown but I dint find the exact answer anywhere.

Comment: This Java code won't compile.

Comment: I think (to be fair) this is Java-ish pseudocode

Comment: yes , it will not compile, I have put some pseudocode for example.

Comment: How fitting that the pseudocode is pseudoformatted... :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just build a `List<Exception>` as you iterate ? Then upon completion throw a `CustomException` (derived from `Exception`) if that list is not empty, and provide the `List<Exception>` as a field in that `CustomException`.

You may prefer not to store a `List<Exception>` but a `List<Info>` where `Info` represents the data resulting in the exception. That would likely be more lightweight.

Better still, create an `ErrorCollator` object that you can add `Exceptions` to as they occur. Once you're done, call `ErrorCollator.throwExceptionIfReqd()`, and that object itself can determine whether to throw the exception (simply, if the `List` is not empty). That way you have a reusable component/pattern that you can use consistently. Perhaps worth working towards, if not doing immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Exception class like

```
Class CustomException extends Exception{

Map listOfExceptions; 


CustomException (Map m){
  ListofExceptions=m;
 }
}
```

Now throw this customer exception when record is >0 or anyother condition.

```
throw new CustomException(listOfExceptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code of how you can add an Exception to a HashMap

```
public class ClassA {

    HashMap hm = new HashMap(); //HashMap Object that holds Exceptions

    public ClassA(){
        try {
            runA();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            hm.put("a", ex); //put Exception in HashMap
        }
        try {
            runB();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            hm.put("b", ex); //put Exception in HashMap
        }
    }

    private void runA() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("a"); //Generate exception a
    }

    private void runB() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("b"); //Generate exception b
    }
}
```

Then you can extend this class by providing some getter function to get your HashMap object and using this loop (Iterator) you can iterate over it:

```
// Get a set of the entries
Set set = hm.entrySet();
// Get an iterator
Iterator i = set.iterator();
// Display elements
while(i.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
  System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
  System.out.println(me.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. In my sample code, I parse a String to int.

> Until end of array, parsing continues. If exception occurs, put it to
>   map. The map contains the field name for which for loop is runnging as
>   key and exception message as value.
>
> At the end of arrays, check the map whether it needs to throws an
>   exception to calling class.

```
public class ExceptionHadlingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A1 a1 = new A1();
        a1.test();
    }
}
class A1 {
    public void test() {

        B1 b1= new B1();
        try {
            b1.test1();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

class B1 {
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> exceptions = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String[] array = {"1","a","2","b","6"};
        for (int i=0; i< array.length ; i++) {
            try {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                exceptions.put(array[i], e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if(exceptions.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Total Number of exception " + exceptions.size());
            for (Entry<String, String> entry : exceptions.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
            }
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    private int parse(String str) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(str);
        return a;
    }
}
```

You can also use customException inside for.